# Possible solutions for returning structs as rvalues without heap allocations: use case neural networks

Tags: python, c, neural-network, malloc, rvalue

MNIST is the hello world of machine learning and I've practiced it with TensorFlow and with [pure python](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning/blob/master/src/network.py) and numpy.

For more practice I am trying to write it in C on my own with only the standard library because I am relatively new to C and it's a great way to learn.

It's taken three weeks, and **a lot** of `SEGFAULTS` but I get 81% accuracy.  Not very good but it's for learning.

The most troubling stuff was of course `malloc/free` for the data in the matrix struct as below:

```
typedef struct matrix{
    int rows, cols;
    float *data;
} matrix;
```

The forward and backward passes have things like:

```
1) matrix dot product
2) matrix add
3) matrix subtract
4) activation function (sigmoid in this case)
```

To avoid memory leaks I pass in three structs like so:

```
void matrix_add(matrix *a, matrix *b, matrix *res);
```

If `res` requires a dimensions change from a previous layer, then I `free` it and do a new `malloc` like so:

```
void zero_out_data(matrix *res, int rows, int cols)
{
  if (res->rows != rows || res->cols != cols)
    {
      if ((res->rows*res->cols) != (rows*cols))
    {
      free(res->data);
      res->data = NULL;
      free(res);
      res = NULL;
      res = malloc(sizeof(matrix));
      // make_matrix will calloc the data based on rows*cols
      // any other init stuff that could be needed
      make_matrix(res, rows, cols);
    }
      res->rows = rows;
      res->cols = cols;
    }
  else {
    res->rows = rows;
    res->cols = cols;
    for (int i =0; i < (rows*cols); i++)
      {
    res->data[i] = 0.0;
      }
  }
}
```

Then I can use that like so:

```
void sigmoid(matrix *z, matrix *res)
{
  zero_out_data(res, z->rows, z->cols); 
  for (int i = 0; i < (z->rows*z->cols); i++)
    {
      res->data[i] = 1.0/(1.0+exp(-z->data[i]));
    }
}
```

This gets **very messy** because a single forward pass has the following:

```
/* forward pass */
for (int k=0; k < (network->num_layers-1); k++)
  {
    matrix_dot(network->weights[k], activation, dot);
    matrix_add(dot, network->biases[k], zs[k]);
    sigmoid(zs[k], activation);
    sigmoid(zs[k], activations[k+1]);
}
/* end forward pass */
```

As you can imagine the backprop gets **alot** messier.  I have to pre-create 8 different matrices, plus many more of those pointers to pointers of matrices like the `activations` and `zs` above, for the gradient descent.

What I would like to be able to do is return a matrix from a function like `matrix_dot` so that I can do:

```
sigmoid(matrix_add(matrix_dot(network->weights[k], activation), network->biases[k]));
```

That's kind of in the style of python/numpy.

Of course I can't return a local variable from a function because it's taken off the stack once the function returns.

If I return a pointer, then the above style will cause sever memory leaks.

Please note: I am not trying to write my own library/framework.  I am simply trying to learn neural networks and coding in C. I have been a python developer for 7 years or so, and my C skills need improvement.

Comment: Why would you get several memory leaks by returning a pointer ? If you free the memory each time you lose a dynamically allocated address, you should not leak.

Comment: If I return a pointer as an rvalue, how can I free it?

Comment: using the free function, your return value will be the address of the dynamically allocated memory, you can free it as long as you keep the address, even if you pass the address from function to function by rvalue.

Comment: Note that free frees memory pointed by a pointer, not the pointer itself.

Comment: How can I store the address if I am passing it from function to function? If I store the return value as a variable, it's not any less messier than passing the result into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Memory leak in `void zero_out_data(matrix *res, int rows, int cols)`

`matrix *res` malloc out of the function and pass to `zero_out_data`. In `zero_out_data`, `res` is free and malloc again. If you want to change pointer `res`'s value, then you need parameter like `matrix **res`.

If you want zero out data, no need malloc new matrix, just malloc the `data` part. I think your `make_matrix` function can malloc memory for `data`.

```
void zero_out_data(matrix *res, int rows, int col) {
      if (res->data == NULL) {
           make_matrix(res, rows, cols);
      } else if (res->rows != rows || res->cols != cols) {
          if ((res->rows*res->cols) != (rows*cols))
             {
               free(res->data);
               res->data = NULL;
               make_matrix(res, rows, cols);
             }
      }
      res->rows = rows;
      res->cols = cols;
      for (int i =0; i < (rows*cols); i++)
      {
            res->data[i] = 0.0;
      } 
}
```

How to implement this: `sigmoid(matrix_add(matrix_dot(network->weights[k], activation), network->biases[k]));` ?

You can use `static` or global variables to implement what you want. This will not be thread safe and reentrant. Examples in below:

```
matrix *matrix_dot(matrix *in_a, matrix *in_b)
{
        static matrix res = {0, 0, NULL};  // static variable

        // calculate the res's cols and rows number
        zero_out_data(&res, res_cols, res_rows);    // malloc new data

        // do some math.

        return &res;
}

// matrix_add will be just like matrix_dot

// I was wrong about sigmod no need new matrix. sigmod can also do it like matrix_dot.
```

You can use global variable replace static variable.

If you want thread-safe or reentrant, then just use local variable, then you can do it like this.

```
matrix *matrix_dot(matrix *in_a, matrix *in_b, matrix *res) 
{
      zero_out_data(res, xxx, xxx);
      // do some math
      return res;
}
// matrix_add will be the same.

// define local variables.
matrix add_res, dot_res, sig_res;
add_res->data = NULL;
dot_res->data = NULL;
sig_res->data = NULL;

sigmod(matrix_add(matrix_dot(network->weights[k], activation, &dot_res), network->biases[k], &add_res),  &sig_res)

// Now remember to free data in matrix
free(add_res->data);
free(dot_res->data);
free(sig_res->data);
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken,`static` could cause trouble later on right?

Comment: Good point about no need for malloc the matrix again, only the data!

Comment: @SamHammamy If no need thread-safe, then `static` will just contain memory not free until program ends.  When use local variable, you need to pass the result, unless you can store your result in parameter.  Like add(int *a, int *b),  after add result stores in a.   I'm not sure about this in your case.

Comment: thanks! I am thinking about creating a new matrix in each of those `matrix_dot`, `matrix_add`, `sigmoid`, etc, then adding a flag to the struct for `can_free = 0`, so I can just free the two inputs if they're not need later, and return a pointer from the functions.  The assumption is each pointer returned from those functions can be freed when it becomes an input to another one.  Hopefully this pans out